# ng-change and ng-click not triggering events in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a radio type button selection in AngularJS. Here is my code.

HTML code:

```
<!-- Page Content -->
<div id="page-wrapper">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h3 class="page-header">Create Products</h3> 
    <div class="media-list" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-default col-md-2 custom-thumbnail">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="platformSel" ng-change="tileSelect(value)" value="win" name="platform-selection" id="win-tile" >
        <i class="center-block fa fa-windows fa-5x"></i>
        <span class="text-center">Windows</span>
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default col-md-offset-custom col-md-2 custom-thumbnail">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="platformSel" ng-change="tileSelect(value)" value="mac" name="platform-selection" id="mac-tile">
        <i class="center-block fa fa-apple fa-5x"></i>
        <span class="text-center">MAC</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</div>
<!-- /#page-wrapper -->
```

Controller code:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/createProduct', {
        templateUrl: 'app/components/createProduct/createProductView.html',
        controller: 'createProductCtrlr'
      });
  }

  function createProductCtrlr($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
    $scope.platformSel = '';
    $scope.tileSelect = function(target) {
      console.log(target + " selected");
    };
  }

  angular
    .module('pacman')
    .controller('createProductCtrlr', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', createProductCtrlr])
    .config(['$routeProvider', config]);
})();
```

I don't see any call happening in 'tileSelect' function. I have no clue why.
Any help is appreciated. I'm new to Angular JS.

Comment: can you create any $scope variable in controller, $scope.test ="loaded", and bind same thing some where in  template {{test}},  then we can check our controller is loaded or not

Comment: @saikumar Yes, I tested it. It is loading.

Comment: can you update your ng-change method like this send ng-change="tileSelect('value')"

Comment: I don't think this syntax  `controller: 'createProductCtrlr'` and this declaration `function createProductCtrlr` works that way. may be try removing quote from createProductCtrlr

Comment: @saikumar Nope. Still no change.

Comment: @YOU both are the same. I even tried your approach. No luck

Comment: @gca If you can put it on *plunkr* it will be quicker for us to help you with the problem.

Comment: correct usage of controller is `angular.module("pacman").controller('createProductCtrlr', createProductCtrlr);`, that's deprecated, I believed.

Comment: But as per @gca, Controller is loaded,

Comment: @saikumar Controller loads and prints other variables in the page. But does not trigger the function when click or change event happened on Button

Answer (score 0):

Is there any error in JavaScript console? As mentioned before you are missing ng-app and ng-controller directives.

```
<div id="page-wrapper" ng-app="pacman" ng-controller="createProductCtrlr">
```

The rest of the code almost correct but since you bind the radio to a model variable there is no need for passing argument in ng-change function.

```
$scope.tileSelect = function() {
    console.log($scope.platformSel + " selected");
};
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/1933/)

Comment: @yunica The code I posted is part of a large application. I have ng-app binded to HTML tag and ng-controller is dynamic and changes based on URL routes. Notice the $routeProvider logic in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging and fixing stuff is real hard. Not as simple as writing code from scratch.

The reason being is, 'data-toggle=buttons' just toggles the bootstrap UI and doesnt make any function calls. Remove the line from html line where class="media-list" and it **works**.

Answer:

**data-toggle="buttons" just toggles the twin button group. Doesnt allow to make function calls.**